# How to use an online C++ compiler in my site

Tags: c++, wordpress, jekyll, github-pages, coliru

I want to create a site (or wikibook or github page) that will have runnable c++ code examples, pretty much like [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) (that apparently is using **coliru** in the `Run this code` button). I'm trying to Google myself through this but each tutorial has too many prerequisites for me follow.

Is there an established best practice or an easy to use toolchain? I thought **jekyll + coliru** would be the best combination but I don't know where to start.

I know this question is too broad, but I don't even know where to invest time. Any of the following would be a great answer (with decreasing order of preference):

- An existing example that I can modify / tweak
- A tutorial on building such a page
- A description of what tools I should use
- A book that describes such a process

Thanks for your help or suggestions.

---

PS1 : I wanted to add a "Wandbox" tag but apparently it doesn't exist

PS2 : I know there is [klipse](http://blog.klipse.tech/cpp/2016/12/29/blog-cpp.html) but the c++ support is very limited so that wouldn't be an ideal solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought jekyll + coliru would be the best combination but I don't know where to start.

You could consider [coliru.js](https://github.com/alamaison/coliru), a JavaScript library for Coliru online compiler.
That way, you add `<script>window.onload = coliru.addRunButtons</script>` to your page to insert buttons into every C++ code block that will compile and run the code and displays the result below the code block.

```
<pre>
    <code data-lang="c++">
        int main()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    </code>
</pre>
```